# HTML mailto subject with '&'

Tags: html, email, special-characters, mailto

I need set subject to '&' sign from client side html.
I have following code,

```
<a href="mailto:no-one@snai1mai1.com?subject=free chocolate&Body=get free hurry.">example</a>
```

i need to set email subject : `free chocolate & cake`

how to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the text; so it becomes:

```
<a href="mailto:no-one@snai1mai1.com?subject=free chocolate %26 cake&Body=get free hurry.">example
</a>
```

`%26` is the Url-encoded representation of `&`